# Webpack: Include vendor in only one module

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I try to migrate one of my project building from browserify to webpack. It's AngularJS@1.7 project and I have multiple bundles: **core** with AngularJS and its dependenciy imports and other specific lazy-loading modules with its specific dependencies. So I have multiple entry points but I only load **core**.js script in index.html. Another modules resolve while routing by my resolver.

One of the lazy-loading modules imports AngularJS and it leads to duplicate code and `WARNING: Tried to load AngularJS more than once`. I want to Webpack check if modules were imported in **core** and load them from it.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work but need to import one extra file `common-vendors.js` in index.html.

My config:

```
export default {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app'),
//...
    entry: {
        'core': './core/core.module',
        'back-office': './back-office/back-office.module',
        'front-office-1': './front-office-2/front-office-2.module',
        'front-office-2': './front-office-3/front-office-3.module'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www')
    },

    mode: config.env,

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                'common-vendors': {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'common-vendors',
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    minChunks: 2
                }
            }
        },
        runtimeChunk: {name: 'core'},
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {mangle: false}
            })
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin()
    ]
}
```

If you know a better solution, feel free to comment.